# How to make mongodb work with countDocuments() and $addFields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document with the following structure:

```
{
    '_id': '',
    'a': '',
    'b': '',
    'c': [
        {
            '_id': '',
            'd': '',
            'f': [
                {
                    'orderDate': 12345,
                    'orderProfit': 12,
                },
                {
                    'orderDate': 67891,
                    'orderProfit': 12341,
                },
                {
                    'orderDate': 23456,
                    'orderProfit': 474,
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            '_id': '',
            'd': '',
            'f': [
                {
                    'orderDate': 14232,
                    'orderProfit': 12222,
                },
                {
                    'orderDate': 643532,
                    'orderProfit': 4343,
                },
                {
                    'orderDate': 33423,
                    'orderProfit': 5555,
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
}
```

`orderDate` is an int64 that represents the date that an order was made

`orderProfit` is an int64 that represents the profit of an order

I needed to return the document that had the biggest "orderDate" and check if the "orderProfit" was the one i was looking for.
For that matter I used a query like this (in an aggregate query):

```
[
    {
        '$addFields': {
            'orders': {
                '$map': {
                    'input': '$c',
                    'as': 'c',
                    'in': {
                        'profit': {
                            '$filter': {
                                'input': '$$c.f',
                                'cond': {
                                    '$eq': [
                                        {
                                            '$max': '$$c.f.orderDate',
                                        },
                                        '$$this.orderDate',
                                    ],
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        '$match': {
            '$or': [
                { 'orders.profit.orderProfit': 500 },
            ],
        },
    },
];
```

It is working properly.

The issue comes when trying to add this query to a `countDocuments()` query in order to fetch the total number of documents.

It is a requirement to use the `countDocuments()`.

I just can't seem to make it work...

$addFields throws as an unknown top level operator. if I remove the $addFields then I can't add to the countDocuments() the query that finds the max date.  If I totally remove it $match is an unknown operator.

```
db.getCollection('orders').countDocuments(
    {
"orders.profit.orderProfit" : {"Query that was shown previously"}

})
```

Comment: just add `{ $count: "count" }` stage at the end.

Comment: Cannot do so, really need it to be a countDocuments(). As it is used in another query.

Comment: you can't add aggregation pipeline in `countDocuments()` method.

Comment: how can i deal with it then?

Comment: if you need both result and count use `$facet`, `{ $facet: { result: [], count: [{ $count: "count" }] } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `countDocuments()` can't allow aggregation pipeline query,

You can use aggregation operators in match query but it cause the performance issues, you can use this when you don't have any way.

- [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) Binds variables for use in the specified expression, and returns the result of the expression,
- `vars`, create variable for orders for your `$addFields` operation,
- `in`, `$map` to iterate loop of `$$orders.profit.orderProfit` nested array and check `$in` condition if your profit amount found then it will return true otherwise false
- `$anyElementTrue` will check returned is true then condition will true otherwise fales

```
db.getCollection('orders').countDocuments({
  $expr: {
    $let: {
      vars: {
        orders: {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$c",
            "as": "c",
            "in": {
              "profit": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$$c.f",
                  "cond": {
                    "$eq": [{ "$max": "$$c.f.orderDate" }, "$$this.orderDate"]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      in: {
        $anyElementTrue: {
          $map: {
            input: "$$orders.profit.orderProfit",
            in: { $in: [500, "$$this"] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bvpn-zvqjYJ)

---

Second option, other way to handle this condition with less operators,

- `$filter` to match your both condition with `orderProfit`
- `$size` to get total result from above `$filter` result
- now `$map` will return array of size that returned by filter
- `$sum` to sum that return result number, if its greater than 0 then condition will be true otherwise false

```
db.getCollection('orders').countDocuments({
  $expr: {
    $sum: {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$c",
        "as": "c",
        "in": {
          $size: {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$$c.f",
              "cond": {
                $and: [
                  { "$eq": [{ "$max": "$$c.f.orderDate" }, "$$this.orderDate"] },
                  { "$eq": ["$$this.orderProfit", 500] }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jHDEbtslrXE)

Comment: Any clue on how to transform this into a BSON document? This as a direct query works as a charm but trying to add it to a BSON document in order to be processed by the golang countDocuments filter parameter is being a nightmare

Comment: i am sorry i don't know go language, ask new question with `go`, `mongo-go` and `mongo-go-driver` language tags you will get exact solution by other members.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

[countDocuments](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/) receives a find `query`, you can't attach an entire pipeline to it.

However `countDocuments` is just a wrapper.

> Returns the count of documents that match the query for a collection or view. The method wraps the $group aggregation stage with a $sum expression to perform the count and is available for use in Transactions.

Basically this method just executes the following aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: yourQuery
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            sum: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
])
```

And then returns `results[0].sum` or `0` depending on result.

So you can just use your own pipeline and add this stage at the end, it would literally be the same complexity wise.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
     ...
     your entire pipeline
     ...
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            sum: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
])
```

If there's any other specific reason you want to not use the aggregation framework let me know, maybe there's a workaround.

Comment: i am curious, what is the difference between `$count` and `$group` by null?

Comment: `$count` is also a wrapper. it just executes the following two stages:
```db.collection.aggregate( [
   { $group: { _id: null, myCount: { $sum: 1 } } },
   { $project: { _id: 0 } }
] )```

Comment: Works well, but actually has to be used in the countDocuments() as this is being in golang and has to be turned into a BSON in order to work as a filter parameter